# Factory pattern for methods with common functionality

Tags: c#, design-patterns, abstract-factory

I have a couple of questions related to patterns and if you guys could help, it'd be great. 
I have an example of a factory pattern code below (code at bottom)- 
The questions I have are -

Question 1.

What if I need to implement common functionality for IPeople for example -

```
bool GotLegs()
{
    return true; //Always returns true for both People types
}
```

So if I want to implement this common method for both Villagers as well as CityPeople, is there another pattern that I could implement?

Question 2

Instead of instantiating an object, is there a way I can directly create a IPeople type. For eg -

```
IPeople people = Factory.GetPeople(PeopleType.URBAN);
```

I understand that static is not an option with interfaces, but just checking to see if there is a way out there.

ACTUAL C# CONSOLE REFERENCE CODE -

```
//Main Prog
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Factory fact = new Factory();
        IPeople people = fact.GetPeople(PeopleType.URBAN);
    }
}

//Empty vocabulary of Actual object
public interface IPeople
{
    string GetName();
}

public class Villagers : IPeople
{

    #region IPeople Members

    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Village Guy";
    }

    #endregion
}

public class CityPeople : IPeople
{

    #region IPeople Members

    public string GetName()
    {
        return "City Guy";
    }

    #endregion
}

public enum PeopleType
{
    RURAL,
    URBAN
}

/// <summary>
/// Implementation of Factory - Used to create objects
/// </summary>
public class Factory
{
    public IPeople GetPeople(PeopleType type)
    {
        IPeople people = null;
        switch (type)
        {
            case PeopleType.RURAL:
                people = new Villagers();
                break;
            case PeopleType.URBAN:
                people = new CityPeople();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return people;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:**

There are several options:

1. Make `GotLegs` an extension method for `IPerson`:

   ```
   public static class PersonExtensions
   {
       public static bool GotLegs(this IPerson person)
       {
           return true;
       }
   }
   ```

   In that case, `IPerson` shouldn't define `GotLegs` itself.
2. Add `GotLegs` to the `IPerson` interface and create a base class `PersonBase` that implements this method and make `CityPeople` and `Villagers` derive from that base class.

**Question 2:**

Simple make `GetPeople` and `Factory` static:

```
public static class Factory
{
    public static IPeople GetPeople(PeopleType type)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Usage would be just as you showed:

```
IPeople people = Factory.GetPeople(PeopleType.URBAN);
```

Comment: So if I implement option 2 from Question 1, then I would have to declare GotLegs() as virtual, and then override in the child classes - Villages & CityPeople, Correct? 


Thanks for the response Daniel!

Comment: @snakepitbean: You only need to declare it as virtual if you really want to override it in the child classes. If you don't want to override it - and that's what I understood from your question - making it virtual is not necessary.

Comment: Sorry Daniel I meant the otherway around. The method GetName() [which is not common] will be an abstract method in the "PeopleBase" Class, and will be implemented in the respective classes Villages & CityPeople, correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you want add common functionality, you can use abstract class instead of interface.
In your case it would be:

```
public abstract class People
{
    public bool GotLegs()
    {
        return true; //Always returns true for both People types
    }

    public abstract string GetName();
}

public class CityPeople : People
{

    #region IPeople Members

    public override string GetName()
    {
        return "City Guy";
    }

    #endregion
}

public class Villagers : People
{

    #region IPeople Members

    public override string GetName()
    {
        return "Village Guy";
    }

    #endregion
}
```